# BitmapFactory.decodeResource() ignoring inScaled

Tags: android, graphics, android-bitmap

It appears that BitmapFactory.decodeResource() is ignoring inScaled when inJustDecodeBounds is also "true".

In this snip of code:

```
Resources res = getResources ();
DisplayMetrics metrics = res.getDisplayMetrics ();

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
options.inScaled = true;
options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH; // resolution of bitmap in resources
options.inTargetDensity = metrics.densityDpi; // screen resolution

options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (res, srcId, options);
logD ("IVH decodeBitmapResource.1: " + options.outWidth + "," + options.outHeight + " - " + srcId);

options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (getResources(), srcId, options);
logD ("IVH decodeBitmapResource.2: " + options.outWidth + "," + options.outHeight + " - " + srcId);
```

I get the following output in my log file:

```
IVH decodeBitmapResource.1: 420,747 - 2130837613
IVH decodeBitmapResource.2: 840,1494 - 2130837613
```

All I did was change inJustDecodeBounds from true to false.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the answer should be obvious: inJustDecodeBounds is supposed to ignore *all* other directives, even scaling.

The following code, when setting inJustDecodeBounds to "true" solves the problem:

```
float scale = (float)metrics.densityDpi / (float)DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH;

imageWidth = (int) (options.outWidth * scale + 0.5);
imageHeight = (int) (options.outHeight * scale + 0.5);
```

That said, come on Google.  You've got all the code in this API; why are you making me rewrite it.  Just provide a different flag that does everything but render the bitmap.  Then, with one flag, I could compute bounds and, by flipping the flag, render a bitmap to exactly fit.

Comment: You say "supposed to" but I don't see it in the javadoc.  So it's either a bug in the docs or a bug in the platform, but we don't know which one.

Comment: Ok, let me put on my "sarcastic" hat.  In my opinion, a lot of Google's Android documentation leaves plenty of semantic details to your imagination.

Comment: You're right.  That's why they let you file bugs:  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Developer%20Documentation